# Problem with combining fastapi with plotly.dash and adding token dependency as auth

Tags: python, dependency-injection, plotly-dash, fastapi

So this is an example dash app mounted to fastapi. I'm using app.mount based on this example from official docs [fastapi-adcanced-wsgi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/). Now I'm stuck because I don't see a way where I can mount this dash app and add fastapi dependency

I would like to add a token or even basic auth to this dash sub app in way you add single dependency to fastapi routes:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

app = FastAPI()

security = HTTPBasic()


@app.get("/users/me")
def read_current_user(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    return {"username": credentials.username, "password": credentials.password}
```

FastAPI example with working dash app.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create the Dash application, make sure to adjust requests_pathname_prefx
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app_dash = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, requests_pathname_prefix='/dash/')

app_dash.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label('Dropdown'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': u'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value='MTL'
    ),

    html.Label('Multi-Select Dropdown'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': u'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value=['MTL', 'SF'],
        multi=True
    ),

    html.Label('Radio Items'),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': u'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value='MTL'
    ),

    html.Label('Checkboxes'),
    dcc.Checklist(
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': u'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value=['MTL', 'SF']
    ),

    html.Label('Text Input'),
    dcc.Input(value='MTL', type='text'),

    html.Label('Slider'),
    dcc.Slider(
        min=0,
        max=9,
        marks={i: 'Label {}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1, 6)},
        value=5,
    ),
], style={'columnCount': 2})

# Now create your regular FASTAPI application

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello_fastapi")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

# Now mount you dash server into main fastapi application
app.mount("/dash", WSGIMiddleware(app_dash.server))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible to use the dependency with the WSGI sub-app, you might consider using middleware as a workaround. Something like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware
from flask import Flask, escape, request
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

flask_app = Flask(__name__)


@flask_app.route("/")
def flask_main():
    name = request.args.get("name", "World")
    return f"Hello, {escape(name)} from Flask!"


app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def auth_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    if (request.url.path.startswith("/v1") and
            request.headers.get('X-Token', None) != "expected_token"):
        return JSONResponse(status_code=403)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response


@app.get("/v2")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


app.mount("/v1", WSGIMiddleware(flask_app))
```

Comment: Omitting FastAPI, is there a similar pattern that would be appropriate for Django + Dash?